# Only the first character of the string is deleted when I've asked it to delete the entire string

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, validation, tkinter

I have performed a data validation check for my computer science coursework, using `sqlite` and `tkinter`, as seen below:

```
    ## Initialise valid to True
    valid = True

    ## Reset each error message if needed
    CLI_errortext_1.set("")
    ...

    ## Get values from entry fields
    CLI_Title = cli_entries[0].get()
    CLI_Forename = cli_entries[1].get()
    CLI_Surname = cli_entries[2].get()
    ...

    if not CLI_Title.isalpha():
        CLI_errortext_1.set("Invalid title. Please use letters only.")
        valid = False

    if not CLI_House_No.isdigit():
        CLI_errortext_4.set("Invalid house number. Please use numbers only.")
        valid = False

    ## Postcode format check

    while True:
        rex = re.compile("^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{2}$")

        if rex.match(CLI_Postcode):
            break
        else:
            CLI_errortext_8.set("Invalid postcode. Please use valid postcode format.")
            valid = False
            break

    ## Length check

    if len(CLI_Phone_No) != 11:
        CLI_errortext_9.set("Invalid phone number. Please use 11 digits.")
        valid = False
        
    ## Email format check

    while True:
        rex = re.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)")

        if rex.match(CLI_Email):
            break
        else:
            CLI_errortext_10.set("Invalid email. Please use a valid email format.")
            valid = False
            break

    ## DOB type and range check

    age = None
    
    try:
        DOB_date = datetime.strptime(CLI_DOB, "%d/%m/%y")
    except ValueError:
        ## Date of birth does not match the expected format, display an error message
        CLI_errortext_11.set("Invalid DOB format. Please use valid date format (dd/mm/yy).")
        valid = False
    else:
        ## Date of birth is in the correct format, continue with the range check
        today = datetime.today()
        age = today.year - DOB_date.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (DOB_date.month, DOB_date.day))

        ## Define the acceptable age range
        min_age = 18
        max_age = 100

        ## Perform the range check
        if age < min_age or age > max_age:
            ## Age is outside the acceptable range, display an error message
            CLI_errortext_11.set(f"Invalid age. Age must be between {min_age} and {max_age}.")
            valid = False
        else:
            ## Age is within the acceptable range, clear the error message
            CLI_errortext_11.set("")
    
    ## All entries presence check
    
    for entry in cli_entries:
        if not entry.get():
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please fill in all required fields.")
            return
```

After entering the correct data type (after originally inserting the wrong data type to check if the error text showed up) when running my code, I was hoping for it to delete the entire string as I had coded it to do. unfortunately, it only deleted the first character, and I don't know what I did for it to do that. I want the entire thing to disappear, not just the first character.

Comment: Please [edit] this down to a [mre]. We don't need all of your code, just enough to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is far too much code. If the question is about deleting a character from a widget, I don't think we need 11 nearly identical widgets when one will do.

Comment: Which string are you referring to? Where are you deleting the string?

Comment: What's the point of the `while True:` loop? You break out of the loop in both the `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: @Barmar when i reset each error message e.g. 'CLI_errortext_1.set("")' at the beginning of the code

Comment: You're not doing that every time the user updates their input, only when the script starts.

Comment: @Barmar oh. well i'm trying to figure out what to do if i want it to clear every time the user inputs something, not just at the beginning

Comment: Run all this  code in the function that you run when they click the submit button.

Comment: @Barmar this code is originally in that function. its under def add_client(): which is the command called after clicking the submit button.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You are not deleting the message, you only put `""` into the box and the program inserts `""` to the first character. It means that the first character is replaced by "" and the rest of the string is not changed. Try this:

```
CLI_errortext_1.delete(0,len(CLI_errortext_1.get()))
```

Comment: Why do you think that `CLI_errortext_1` is an `Entry` widget (OP use `CLI_errortext_1.set("")` and `Entry` widget does not have `set()`)? Based on OP code, it is most likely a tkinter `StringVar`